# Разрешённая нагрузка СР

Tags: wordpress, хостинг

Взяли готовый интернет-магазин на WordPress и запустили его на бесплатном хостинге Beget, там разрешённая нагрузка CP 10 в день. В итоге часа за полтора "работы" (просто разбирались в шаблоне) и добавлении пары своих товаров, был превышен этот лимит. Посмотрел статистику, и там аж 40 СР оказалось. Это всё на самом деле должно быть так, или шаблон дико прожорливый и лучше взять другой?

Comment: Дело в теме, плагинах и еще много в чем может быть. Для интернет магазина самый дешевый хостинг тоже не годиться)

Comment: А сколько нужно для интернет магазина? Мы сейчас на бесплатном хостинге хотели сначала просто настроить сайт, а в итоге он помер через полтора часа. На том же Begete например несколько тарифов, 10 сайтов, 25 сайтов. Увеличивается разумеется цена и только место на диске. А в итоге для всех сайтов в общем выделяется 65 СР в день. Это просто шутка какая-то, 25 сайтов, когда у нас один сожрал 40СР за 2 часа...

Comment: так не должно быть, Wordpress это, конечно, не супер быстрая CMS, но всё не настолько плохо